# XML LINQ: How to use select with where?

Tags: xml, linq, select, where-clause

I have an XML catalog with product Name and product Price.

I successfully select all items from my catalog with this code:

```
  var products = xElem.Descendants("catalog")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ProductPrice= x.Element("Price").Value,
                ProductName = x.Element("Name").Value
            });
```

How do I modify the above code to select only items whose names contain "abc" and "xyz"? 
In SQL I'd use WHERE and LIKE, here, I want to do this with LINQ.
Thanks.

*MORE INFO*

Actually, I want the user to be able to query flexibly. So if the user types "red shirt cotton" then I will show all items that has all those 3 terms: "red", "shirt" and "cotton". The number of "where" terms are not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var products = from d in xElem.Descendants("catalog")
               where d.Element("Name").Value.Contains("abc")
                  || d.Element("Name").Value.Contains("xyz")
               select new { Name  = d.Element("Name") .Value, 
                            Price = d.Element("Price").Value
                          }
;
```