# How to add a where clause inside select query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select, where-clause

```
<PersVeh id="V0001" LocationRef="L0001" RatedDriverRef="D0001">
  <Manufacturer>FORD</Manufacturer> 
  <Model>TAURUS SE</Model> 
  <ModelYear>2007</ModelYear> 
  <VehBodyTypeCd>PP</VehBodyTypeCd> 
  <POLKRestraintDeviceCd>E</POLKRestraintDeviceCd> 
  <EstimatedAnnualDistance>
    <NumUnits>011200</NumUnits> 
  </EstimatedAnnualDistance>
  <VehIdentificationNumber>1FAFP53U37A160207</VehIdentificationNumber> 
  <VehSymbolCd>12</VehSymbolCd> 
  <VehRateGroupInfo>
    <RateGroup>16</RateGroup> 
    <CoverageCd>COMP</CoverageCd> 
  </VehRateGroupInfo>
  <VehRateGroupInfo>
    <RateGroup>21</RateGroup> 
    <CoverageCd>COLL</CoverageCd> 
  </VehRateGroupInfo>
```

I'm brand new to Linq and I'm hoping that someone can help me with what may or may not be a simple problem.

For the above xml sample I'm using the following code:

```
var result = from item in doc.Descendants(n + "PersVeh")
             where item.Attribute("id").Value == "V0001"
             select new
             {
                RatedDriverRef = (string)item.Attribute("RatedDriverRef"),
                LocationRef = (string)item.Attribute("LocationRef"),
                ModelYear = (string)item.Element(n + "ModelYear") ?? "9999",
                VehBodyTypeCd = (string)item.Element(n + "VehBodyTypeCd") ?? "XX",
                POLKRestraintDeviceCd = (string)item.Element(n + "POLKRestraintDeviceCd") ?? "0",
                EstimatedAnnualDistance = (string)item.Element(n + "EstimatedAnnualDistance").Element(n + "NumUnits") ?? "999999",
                VehIdentificationNumber = (string)item.Element(n + "VehIdentificationNumber") ?? "VIN not found",
                VehSymbolCd = (string)item.Element(n + "VehSymbolCd") ?? "00"
             };
```

The problem I'm having is with the **VehRateGroupInfo** nodes. I need to extract the **RateGroup** number based on the **CoverageCd**.

In other words, something like this:

```
CompSymbol = item.Element(n + "VehRateGroupInfo").Element(n + "RateGroup").Value
             where item.Element(n + "VehRateGroupInfo").Element(n + "CoverageCd").Value == "COMP"
```

Is it possible to do this within the select or do I need a separate query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML LINQ: How to use select with where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761006/xml-linq-how-to-use-select-with-where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with query syntax:

```
CompSymbol = (from vehRateGroup in item.Descendants(n + "VehRateGroupInfo")
              where vehRateGroup.Element(n + "CoverageCd").Value == "COMP"
              select vehRateGroup.Element(n + "RateGroup").Value).Single()
```

Here's a similar solution with method syntax:

```
CompSymbol = item.Descendants(n + "VehRateGroupInfo")
                 .Single(x => x.Element(n + "CoverageCd").Value == "COMP")
                 .Element(n + "RateGroup").Value
```